# How do you know which element wins in "flutter_fortune_wheel"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the "flutter_fortune_wheel" package. I can't figure out how to know which element wins? Can you help with that?

I wrote the code as follows:

[image]

But when I try to listen to changes in "onAnimationEnd" function as follows, I get error "StateError (Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.)":

[image]

Comment: please include your code as _text_, even if the highlight is imaged!